# Awk - Comparing two files and extracting data for each column

Tags: bash, awk

I have file1 as follows.

```
CQUAD4   16200015 15998317 16218870 16218869 16218944 16200867     1596    4.426 
CQUAD4   16200031 15998317 16218869 16218870 16200020 16218920     1596    4.426 
CQUAD4   16200032 15998317 16220790 16218871 16216987 16200018     1596    4.426 
CQUAD4   16200033 15998317 16218871 16220790 16200871 16217011     1596    4.426 
CQUAD4   16200034 15998317 16218876 16218877 16216993 16216992     1596    4.426
```

I have file2 as below.

```
TEMP 579 16218870 82.63586
TEMP 579 16218869 82.63954
TEMP 579 16218944 82.5782
TEMP 579 16200867 82.57428
TEMP 579 16200020 82.69743
TEMP 579 16218920 82.70086
TEMP 579 16220790 82.6325
TEMP 579 16218871 82.63642
TEMP 579 16216987 82.69798
TEMP 579 16200018 82.69431
TEMP 579 16200871 82.5707
TEMP 579 16217011 82.57488
TEMP 579 16218876 82.65606
TEMP 579 16218877 82.66002
TEMP 579 16216993 82.71999
TEMP 579 16216992 82.71633
```

I have to search for field4 from file1 in field3 of file2 and extract the data from field4 of file2 and add it to file1.

I want an output as below.

```
CQUAD4   16200015 15998317 16218870 16218869 16218944 16200867     1596    4.426 82.63586
CQUAD4   16200031 15998317 16218869 16218870 16200020 16218920     1596    4.426 82.63954
CQUAD4   16200032 15998317 16220790 16218871 16216987 16200018     1596    4.426 82.6325
CQUAD4   16200033 15998317 16218871 16220790 16200871 16217011     1596    4.426 82.5707
CQUAD4   16200034 15998317 16218876 16218877 16216993 16216992     1596    4.426 82.65606
```

I tried following codes none of them are working.

```
 awk 'NR==FNR {a[$3]=$4; next} ($4 in a){print $0,a[$3]}' File2 File1 > Output
 awk 'NR==FNR {A[$3]=$4; next} ($4 in A){$10 = A[$3]}1' File2 File1 > Output
```

Can someone help me with a correct code please?

Comment: it's totally unclear what the output has to do with the input, esp. its relation to `file2`.

Comment: Field 4 from file2 must be added to last field of file1 if field4 of file1 is found in field3 of file2

Comment: that sentence is very hard to understand. Please add it to your question and maybe explain a bit more.

Comment: I have added this sentence in the question. I have to search field4 of file1 (16218870) in field3 of file2 and extract it's corresponding value (82.63586) and add it to last column of file1

Comment: There are typos in your 2 attempts: try `print $0,a[$4]` with the first one and `$10 = A[$4]` with the second.

Comment: This is a variation of the most frequently asked question on this forum, please look at the archives and **think** about what `$4 in a` and `print a[$3]` in your code, `($4 in a){print $0,a[$3]}`, mean in plain language which will then tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: I recommend that yousimplify your sample data. 3-4 columns, 2-3 rows that cover any corner cases you anticipate. Too hard to read! (-;! If you can live with data sorted on your key columns, then look at the `join` utility. Good luck!

Comment: `print a[$3]` says to use the 3rd field from `file1` as an index ... but nowhere in your description do you reference the 3rd field from `file1`

Comment: You are probably better off using a small python script which can process each element from list1, find the data in list2 and generate the output. If you have lists that are too long, use an indexed SQLite database as temp storage.  It might well even be that you can do all this using a query over two tables.